# json.loads() doesn't work on json file retrived from tweepy streaming

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, jupyter-notebook, tweepy

I try to extreact data from twitter json file retrived by using tweepy streaming
Here is my code for streaming:

```
class MyListener(Stream):
t_count=0

def on_data(self, data):
    print (data)
    self.t_count += 0
    #stop by 
    if self.t_count >= 5000:
        sys.exit("exit")
    return True

def on_error(self, status):
    print (status)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    stream = MyListener(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)
    stream.filter(track=['corona'], languages = ["en"])
```

Here is my code for reading the file:

```
with open("covid-test-out", "r") as f:
count = 0
for line in f:
    data = json.loads(line)
```

Then I got the error

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Here is one line in the json file. I noticed that there is a b-prefix in front of each line but when I check the type of the line, it is not bytes object but still string object. And I am not even sure if this is the reason that I can not get the correct data.

> b'{"created_at":"Mon Nov 22 07:37:46 +0000 2021","id":1462686730956333061,"id_str":"1462686730956333061","text":"RT @corybernardi: Scientists 'mystified'. \n\nhttps:\/\/t.co\/rvTYCUEQ74","source":"\u003ca href=\"https:\/\/mobile.twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter Web App\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":1336870146242056192,"id_str":"1336870146242056192","name":"Terence Byrnes","screen_name":"byrnes_terence","location":null,"url":null,"description":"Retired Aussie. Against mandatory vaccinations, government interference in our lives, and the climate cult. Now on Gab Social as a backup : Terence50","translator_type":"none","protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":960,"friends_count":1012,"listed_count":3,"favourites_count":15163,"statuses_count":171876,"created_at":"Thu Dec 10 03:08:01 +0000 2020","utc_offset":null,"time_zone":null,"geo_enabled":false,"lang":null,"contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"F5F8FA","profile_background_image_url":"","profile_background_image_url_https":"","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_link_color":"1DA1F2","profile_sidebar_border_color":"C0DEED","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/1428994180458508292\/fT2Olt4J_normal.jpg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/1428994180458508292\/fT2Olt4J_normal.jpg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/1336870146242056192\/1631520259","default_profile":true,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null,"withheld_in_countries":[]},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"retweeted_status":{"created_at":"Sun Nov 21 19:42:14 +0000 2021","id":1462506658421112834,"id_str":"1462506658421112834","text":"Scientists 'mystified'. \n\nhttps:\/\/t.co\/rvTYCUEQ74","source":"\u003ca href=\"https:\/\/mobile.twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter Web App\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":80965423,"id_str":"80965423","name":"CoryBernardi.com.au","screen_name":"corybernardi","location":"Adelaide ","url":"http:\/\/www.corybernardi.com.au","description":"Get your free Weekly Dose of Common Sense email at https:\/\/t.co\/MAJpp7iZJy.\n\nLaughing at liars and leftists since 2006. Tweets deleted weekly to infuriate losers.","translator_type":"none","protected":false,"verified":true,"followers_count":47794,"friends_count":63,"listed_count":461,"favourites_count":112,"statuses_count":55,"created_at":"Thu Oct 08 22:54:55 +0000 2009","utc_offset":null,"time_zone":null,"geo_enabled":false,"lang":null,"contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"C0DEED","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_link_color":"1DA1F2","profile_sidebar_border_color":"C0DEED","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/1446336496827387904\/Ay6QRHQt_normal.jpg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/1446336496827387904\/Ay6QRHQt_normal.jpg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/80965423\/1633668973","default_profile":true,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null,"withheld_in_countries":[]},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"is_quote_status":false,"quote_count":5,"reply_count":30,"retweet_count":40,"favorite_count":136,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"urls":[{"url":"https:\/\/t.co\/rvTYCUEQ74","expanded_url":"https:\/\/apnews.com\/article\/coronavirus-pandemic-science-health-pandemics-united-nations-fcf28a83c9352a67e50aa2172eb01a2f","display_url":"apnews.com\/article\/corona\u2026","indices":[26,49]}],"user_mentions":[],"symbols":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"possibly_sensitive":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"en"},"is_quote_status":false,"quote_count":0,"reply_count":0,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"urls":[{"url":"https:\/\/t.co\/rvTYCUEQ74","expanded_url":"https:\/\/apnews.com\/article\/coronavirus-pandemic-science-health-pandemics-united-nations-fcf28a83c9352a67e50aa2172eb01a2f","display_url":"apnews.com\/article\/corona\u2026","indices":[44,67]}],"user_mentions":[{"screen_name":"corybernardi","name":"CoryBernardi.com.au","id":80965423,"id_str":"80965423","indices":[3,16]}],"symbols":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"possibly_sensitive":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"en","timestamp_ms":"1637566666722"}'

Comment: You need to decode the byte string.

Comment: @Barmar yeah I tried that but I got an error " 'str' object has no attribute 'decode' "

Comment: Does the file contain a literal `b'` at the beginning?

Comment: @Barmar it does and I still got the error

Comment: It's not a JSON file.

Comment: You could use `json.loads(ast.literal_eval(line))`

Comment: did you create this file? It seems you saved data in wrong way. Maybe you used `str()` and this made all problems. You should write file in bytes-mode and then you don't have to use `str()`